Solving differential equations for forced oscillations
The following two differential equations are given in Ref. (Ref: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.045002)
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 \ddot{p}_x+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}p_x+\Omega _z\dot{p}_y=mca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}\sin \left( \omega _{\text{L}}t \right)\\
 \ddot{p}_y+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}p_y-\Omega _z\dot{p}_x=mca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}\cos \left( \omega _{\text{L}}t \right)\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$
The reference final results are given:
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 p_x=-\frac{2mca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}\sin \left( \omega _-t \right)}{\left( \omega _{\text{L}}+\omega _{\text{B}}+\Omega _z \right) \left( \omega _{\text{B}}-\omega _{\text{L}} \right)}\cos \left( \omega _+t \right)\\
 p_y=\frac{2mca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}\sin \left( \omega _-t \right)}{\left( \omega _{\text{L}}+\omega _{\text{B}}+\Omega _z \right) \left( \omega _{\text{B}}-\omega _{\text{L}} \right)}\sin \left( \omega _+t \right)\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$
Here is the attempt I made:
Let $p=p_x+ip_y$, then
$$
\left[ \ddot{p}_x-\Omega _z\dot{p}_x+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}p_x \right] +i\left[ \ddot{p}_y-\Omega _z\dot{p}_y+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}p_y \right] =imca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}\left[ \cos \left( \omega _{\text{L}}t \right) -i\sin \left( \omega _{\text{L}}t \right) \right] 
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\ddot{p}-i\Omega _z\dot{p}+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}p=imca\omega _{\text{L}}e^{-i\omega _{\text{L}}t}
$$
Assuming $p=Ae^{-i\omega_+t}$. (The assumptions here are mainly trying to cobble together the results of the ref)
$$
A=-\frac{mca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}e^{i\omega _-t}}{\omega _{+}^{2}+\Omega _z\omega _++\left( \Omega _z/2 \right) ^2-\left( \sqrt{\Omega _{z}^{2}/4+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}} \right) ^2}
$$
where $\sqrt{\frac{\Omega _{z}^{2}}{4}+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}}=\omega _{\text{B}}+\frac{\Omega _z}{2},\ \omega _+=\frac{\omega _{\text{B}}+\omega _{\text{L}}}{2},\ \omega _-=\frac{\omega _{\text{B}}-\omega _{\text{L}}}{2}$. Then,
$$
\left( \omega _++\frac{\Omega _z}{2} \right) ^2-\left( \omega _{\text{B}}+\frac{\Omega _z}{2} \right) ^2=-\frac{\left( \omega _++\omega _{\text{B}}+\Omega _z \right) \left( \omega _{\text{B}}-\omega _{\text{L}} \right)}{2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
p=Ae^{-i\omega _+t}=\frac{2imca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}e^{-i\omega _{\text{L}}t}}{\left( \omega _++\omega _{\text{B}}+\Omega _z \right) \left( \omega _{\text{B}}-\omega _{\text{L}} \right)}
$$
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 p_x=\text{Re}p=\frac{2mca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}}{\left( \omega _++\omega _{\text{B}}+\Omega _z \right) \left( \omega _{\text{B}}-\omega _{\text{L}} \right)}\sin \left( \omega _{\text{L}}t \right)\\
 p_y=\text{Im}p=\frac{2mca\omega _{\text{L}}^{2}}{\left( \omega _++\omega _{\text{B}}+\Omega _z \right) \left( \omega _{\text{B}}-\omega _{\text{L}} \right)}\cos \left( \omega _{\text{L}}t \right)\\
\end{array} \right. 
$$
But it is clearly noticed that the results are still somewhat different from those in Ref.

Since the link is paywalled, it's important to include all relevant info. In that regard: 1) what are their initial conditions? 2) you should state the definitions of $\omega_B,\omega_\pm $ up front rather than within the attempted derivation.

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4949401/solving-for-coefficient-factors-by-differential-equations

I will first give a direct solution to the differential equation
$$\ddot{p}-i\Omega _z\dot{p}+\Omega _{\theta}^{2}p=iA e^{-i\omega _{\text{L}}t}$$
where I have taken $A:=mca\omega_{\text{L}}^2$ to minimize excess algebra.
First, we seek the homogeneous solutions. Introducing the ansatz $p=e^{i\omega t}$, the LHS vanishes if
$$-\omega^2 +\Omega_z \omega +\Omega_\theta^2=0\implies \omega =\frac{\Omega_z}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{\Omega_z^2}{4}+\Omega_\theta^2}$$
These frequencies simplify to $\omega=\omega_\text{B},\omega_\text{B}+\Omega_z$ upon introducing the notation $$\Omega_\text{B}=\sqrt{\frac{\Omega_z^2}{4}+\Omega_\theta^2}-\frac{\Omega_z}{2}$$
We next need a particular solution, and the most obvious one to guess is of the form $Be^{-i\omega_\text{L} t}$. This requires
$$(-\omega_\text{L}^2 -\Omega_z \omega_\text{L}+\Omega_\theta^2)B=iA\implies B=\frac{iA}{-\omega_\text{L}^2 -\Omega_z \omega_\text{L}+\Omega_\theta^2}$$
Since the definition of $\omega_\text{B}$ amounts to $\Omega_\theta^2=\omega_\text{B}^2+\omega_\text{B} \omega_\text{L}$, this simplifies to $$B=\frac{iA}{(\omega_\text{B}-\omega_\text{L})(\omega_\text{B}+\omega_\text{L}+\Omega_z)}$$
Hence the general solution to the inhomogeneous equation is
$$p(t)=\frac{C_1 e^{-i\omega_\text{B} t}+C_2 e^{i(\omega_\text{B}+\Omega_z)}+ iA e^{-i\omega_\text{L} t}}{(\omega_\text{B}-\omega_\text{L})(\omega_\text{B}+\omega_\text{L}+\Omega_z)}$$
where for convenience I've folded the homogeneous solutions into the numerator of the inhomogeneous solution. Now suppose we want to study this solution near the resonance $\omega_\text{B}\approx \omega_\text{L}$. Then the numerator behaves like $$(C_1+iA) e^{-i\omega_\text{L} t}+C_2 e^{i(\omega_\text{L}+\Omega_z)}$$ whereas the denominator vanishes as $\omega_B-\omega_L$. Hence the solution will blow up in this limit unless $C_2=0, C_1=-iA$. This yields
$$p(t)=\frac{iA (e^{-i\omega_\text{L} t}-e^{-i\omega_\text{B} t})}{(\omega_\text{B}-\omega_\text{L})(\omega_\text{B}+\omega_\text{L}+\Omega_z)}$$
If we introduce $\omega_{\pm}=(\omega_\text{B}\pm\omega_\text{L})/2$, some work with Euler's formula simplifies this to
$$p(t)=\frac{-2A \sin(\omega_- t)e^{-i \omega_+ t}}{(\omega_\text{B}-\omega_\text{L})(\omega_\text{B}+\omega_\text{L}+\Omega_z)}$$
Taking real and imaginary parts then recovers the reference solution. (In the notation of the paper, we have $p(t)=-e^{-i\omega_+ t}p_\perp(t)$ where $p_\perp(t)$ is defined in Eq. (4).) So this solution is valid and appropriate for studying the limit $\omega_\text{B}\to \omega_\text{L}$.
